# standardize company names in pandas dynamically

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, text-processing, fuzzywuzzy

i have a dataframe with company names

df:

| company_name |
| --- |
| abc Inc |
| abc Inc Bolingbrook |
| enterprise badh Shah |
| enterprise Financial |
| enterprise Financial Shah |
| bass Dance |
| bass School of Dance |
| david Warner |
| david Warner Real Estate Inc |
| david Warneranita sampath |
| Dr anitha sampath |
| Dranil kumar Gyan prasad |
| Dranil and kumar Mortgage Corporation |
| Drbadh Shah |
| Drvenky Patel |
| Drs krishna and Rama lingam |

i want to standardize the company_name so that the output looks like this

output df:

| company_name | standardized_company_name |
| --- | --- |
| abc Inc | abc Inc |
| abc Inc Bolingbrook | abc Inc |
| enterprise badh Shah | enterprise Financial |
| enterprise Financial | enterprise Financial |
| enterprise Financial Shah | enterprise Financial |
| bass Dance | bass School of Dance |
| bass School of Dance | bass School of Dance |
| david Warner | david Warner |
| david Warner Real Estate Inc | david Warner |
| david Warneranita sampath | david Warner |
| Dr anitha sampath | anitha sampath |
| Dranil kumar Gyan prasad | anil kumar |
| Dranil and Gyan Mortgage Corporation | anil kumar |
| Drbadh Shah | badh Shah |
| Drvenky Patel | venky Patel |
| Drs krishna and Rama lingam | krishna and Rama lingam |

NOTE: the standardization has no rules but similar company_names should have same standardized_company_name

for eg:  standardized_company_name can also be like this

| company_name | standardized_company_name |
| --- | --- |
| abc Inc | abc |
| abc Inc Bolingbrook | abc |
| enterprise badh Shah | enterprise |
| enterprise Financial | enterprise |
| enterprise Financial Shah | enterprise |

i tried removing stopwords using regex replace  but its not effective. Thanks in advance.............

i also tried splitting

```
def func(val):
    val=val.split(' ',2)
    return ' '.join([val[0]])

name = unique[['company_name','state']]
name['standardized_company_name']=name['company_name'].apply(func)
```

but what i get is

output i got :

| company_name | standardized_company_name |
| --- | --- |
| abc Inc | abc |
| abc Inc Bolingbrook | abc |
| enterprise badh Shah | enterprise |
| enterprise Financial | enterprise |
| enterprise Financial Shah | enterprise |
| bass Dance | bass |
| bass School of Dance | bass |
| david Warner | david |
| david Warner Real Estate Inc | david |
| david Warneranita sampath | david |
| Dr anitha sampath | Dr |
| Dranil kumar Gyan prasad | Dranil |
| Dranil and kumar Mortgage Corporation | Dranil |
| Drbadh Shah | Drbadh |
| Drvenky Patel | Drvenky |
| Drs krishna and Rama lingam | Drs |

Answer (score 2):

Firstly create a function that do this for you:-

```
def func(val):
    val=val.split(' ',2)
    if len(val)==1:
        return val[0]
    else:
        return ' '.join([val[0],val[1]])
```

Now just make use of `apply()` method:-

```
df['standardized_company_name']=df['company_name'].apply(func)
```

Output:-

```
    company_name                     standardized_company_namedf
0   abc Inc                          abc Inc
1   abc Inc Bolingbrook              abc Inc
2   enterprise badh Shah             enterprise badh
3   enterprise Financial             enterprise Financial
4   enterprise Financial Shah        enterprise Financial
5   bass Dance                       bass Dance
6   bass School of Dance             bass School
7   david Warner                     david Warner
8   david Warner Real Estate Inc     david Warner
9   david Warneranita sampath        david Warneranita
```

then as you mention your condition in comment use this:-

```
df['standardized_company_name']=df['standardized_company_name'].str.replace('badh','Financial')
df['standardized_company_name']=df['standardized_company_name'].str.replace('bass Dance','bass School')
```

Comment: it has names like Dr abc Dr bcc etc in that case it will take all as Dr .? i will update my question..

Comment: if company name has only word then ur logic breaks it returns(list index out of range)

Comment: ohh...fixed it and updated answer ...now kindly have a look

Comment: but the standard names should be same.... for eg enterprise should either have standardname as enterprise or enterprise Financial not both  similarly bass too either bass or bass school for all records.

Comment: ohh...fixed this as well and updated answer ....now kindly have a look